# How to change select component tags in ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Hi everyone I have the following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd-4-23-1-forked-1qox99).

I am trying to do following.

When the user selects one of the items from the dropdown list, it appears in select with a close tag.

So I need somehow customize and add besides that close icon also edit button. How can I achieve that?

```
    import React from "react";
    import "antd/dist/antd.css";
    import { Select } from "and";

    const { Option } = Select;
    const arr = ["first value", "second value", "third value"];
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <Select
            mode="tags"
            size={"large"}
            placeholder="Please select"
            style={{
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            {arr?.map((el) => (
              <Option key={el} value={el}>
                {el}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

P.S. unfortunately I am using antd version `3.x.x`and it does not support `tagRender` prop. And there is no way to upgrade to the latest version.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: After a quick look at the library, I found that you can use custom rendering for tags. I don't know if you can use it in `3.x.x`, but here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/5fh1np?file=/demo.js

If you can use this logic, you could create any kind of edit mechanism with html and react.js

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann, thanks for helping, but `3.x.x` version not supporting `tagRender` props.

Comment: So by adding that edit button, what do you want to achieve? The user should be able to edit the selected tag, to create a custom tag?

Comment: yes, the user should be able to edit the tag text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround solution for `antd` version `3.3.0`; You can add a custom icon to all the options and hide these icons when they are in the select dropdown like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Select } from "antd";
import { EditOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import "./demo.css";
const { Option } = Select;
const arr = ["first value", "second value", "third value"];

const App = () => {
  const handleEditClicked = (e, el) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(el);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        mode="tags"
        size={"large"}
        placeholder="Please select"
        style={{
          width: "100%"
        }}
      >
        {arr?.map((el) => (
          <Option key={el} value={el}>
            <EditOutlined
              className="customEditIcon"
              onClick={(e) => handleEditClicked(e, el)}
            />
            {el}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is the related css to hide icons on dropdown:

```
.customEditIcon.anticon-edit:before {
  display: none;
}

.ant-select-dropdown .customEditIcon {
  display: none;
}
```

You can take a look at [this forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-select-tag-3-3-0-fo9kbo?file=/demo.js) sandbox for a live working example of this workaround solution.